# Execute php without refreshing page

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, ajax

I want to execute the javascript code through php when the submit button is clicked......this code does it but the page refreshes.....i dont want the page to refresh......can I achieve it through ajax or jquery and how?

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            .popup
            {
                visibility:hidden;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post">
        <div id="Popup" class="popup">
            Sorry! The vehicle is already booked on the corresponding date.
            Select a different date or book another vehicle.
        </div>
        <input type="submit" name="submit" value="display">
        </form>
        <?php
            if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
            {
                echo '<script>document.getElementById("Popup").style.visibility="visible";</script>';
            }
        ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: what do you mean by 'the same thing'

Comment: Learn the basics of javascript, you can easily tackle similar issues.

Comment: You can't "execute PHP" without refreshing.  PHP is a server-side language, so as such,  it only executes when the page is generated.  Also, you don't need to use PHP to do this - just put the <script> directly in the HTML, or better yet, don't hide the popup in CSS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot do this with PHP. As PaulProgrammer stated PHP can only execute when the page is generated as it is a server side language. You need a client side language such as JavaScript to do this. Here is an example of code you can try out. Don't just take the example, but learn what each of the components do:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style>
            #popup
            {
                display:none;
            }
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <button id="showbtn">Show Popup</button>
        <div id="popup">
            Sorry!The vehicle is already booked on the corresponding date.
            Select a different date or book another vehicle.
        </div>

        <script>
            const mypopup = document.getElementById("popup");
            const mybutton = document.getElementById("showbtn");

            mybutton.addEventListener('click', function(event) {
                mypopup.style.display = "block";
            })
        </script>

    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

try to use javascript to execute on second plane the code